# How to process output from an AutoIt script that records user activity?

Tags: autoit

I wrote a script that records the user activity and stores it in a text file every 10 seconds (so I know how much time the user spent on a file or folder). Which way is the best for processing that data, such as aggregate by activity name?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen your data, but I presume you have, at least, something like:

Activity - TimeStamp

The very easiest method would be to use Excel ( Or Google Sheets ) to  Pivot the data and use native charting.

To get the duration, you can add a third column that calculates the difference in the current row and the following row:   R1C3 = R2C2-R1C2.   Just copy that down the column to get the duration from the current activity to the next.  (Of course, the final line will fail as R(n+1)C2 won't have a value.